# Remove block using unsetChild in Magento1

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, event-observer, xml

I have an observer which this event: `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`. This is the code from my method:

```
$_block = $event->getBlock();
$_type = $_block->getType();
if ($_type == 'catalog/product_view'){
   $_block->unsetChild('product.info.container1');
}
```

This is the xml:

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
       <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
       <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
```

I want to remove this block of type `core/template_facade`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this won't work with the `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` event.

Your code looks good I suggest you use the `controller_action_layout_render_before` event instead

On top of that the `unsetChild` method accepts an alias as a parameter so you probably want to try:

```
$_block->unsetChild('container1');
```